# How to get Nested JSON data in effiecient way?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have the following JSON data from API, from which I want to get only specific values in an array:

Here is the sample object data:

```js
{
    "matches":[
        {
            "parsedPerson":{
                "personType":"NATURAL",
                "personRole":"PRIMARY",
                "mailingPersonRoles":[
                    "ADDRESSEE"
                ],
                "gender":{
                    "gender":"MALE",
                    "confidence":0.9325842696629214
                },
                "addressingGivenName":"Brandyn",
                "addressingSurname":"Kramer",
                "outputPersonName":{
                    "terms":[
                        {
                            "string":"Brandyn",
                            "termType":"GIVENNAME"
                        },
                        {
                            "string":"Kramer",
                            "termType":"SURNAME"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "parserDisputes":[
                
            ],
            "likeliness":0.9427026792672768,
            "confidence":0.9433333333333334
        }
    ],
    "bestMatch":{
        "parsedPerson":{
            "personType":"NATURAL",
            "personRole":"PRIMARY",
            "mailingPersonRoles":[
                "ADDRESSEE"
            ],
            "gender":{
                "gender":"MALE",
                "confidence":0.9325842696629214
            },
            "addressingGivenName":"Brandyn",
            "addressingSurname":"Kramer",
            "outputPersonName":{
                "terms":[
                    {
                        "string":"Brandyn",
                        "termType":"GIVENNAME"
                    },
                    {
                        "string":"Kramer",
                        "termType":"SURNAME"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "parserDisputes":[
            
        ],
        "likeliness":0.9427026792672768,
        "confidence":0.9433333333333334
    }
}
```

For example, I want to get 'string' value where

```
 'termType=GIVENNAME' (Tom,Henry) 
 'termType=SURNAME'   (Smith)     
  and 'gender'        (MALE)
```

As a beginner, if I want to get 'gender', I will do the following:

```
var gender = data.bestMatch.parsedPerson.gender.gender
```

but I do not think this is the right way to approach this, I want to get all the data in an array using a loop, something like this, or may be more better way:

```
var Given = [Tom,Henry] 
var Surname = [Smith]   
var gender = [MALE]
```

I am trying to use following code snippet to get values where `termType = GIVENNAME` but it gives **undefined** as an output:

```
const findName = (obj, key) => {
   const arr = obj['outputPersonName'];
   if(arr.length){
      const result = arr.filter(el => {
         return el['termType'] === key;
      });
      if(result && result.length){
         return result.string;
      }
      else{
         return '';
      }
   }
}
console.log(findName(data.parsedPerson, 'GIVENNAME'));
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you provided for JSON is not JSON

Comment: Here's a JSON tool: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: Thank you for your help, I trimmed the output to make it simple, but now I have updated the whole output coming from the script run.

Comment: It's still not JSON

Comment: There are no equal signs in JSON and all strings are enclosed in quotes.  Starting with correct JSON is essential to accessing the data.

Comment: An EagleEye would have caught this in the beginning.

Comment: I apologize but script gives this output, how to convert it into correct JSON, I am using the following statements:
`var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL,options).getContentText();`
  `var data = JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: @Cooper, please check now, I have been able to get the correct JSON data.

Comment: Currently your search resulted in an array with only one match and so best match is the same as the one element in the array.

Comment: `result.string`???

Comment: yes, want to get this `"string" : "Brandyn"`

Comment: You can pass `JSON.parse` a reviver function along with your response. That reviver function walks the JSON document tree as it parses the response so you can use it to target the nodes in the JSON document you want to inspect. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: ```obj['outputPersonName']```  returns an object ```{terms: [object, object]}``` so you have to access the correct properties, a good approach would be to debug on each step by logging the output. 
```const arr = obj['outputPersonName'].terms;``` this will return the terms array.

When returning the result you can not access the object directly since filter returns a new array with matched options. So again logging here would be good idea to see the result.

```if(result && result.length) return result[0].string;```

Comment: I'm seeing a single JSON formatted record being returned to you. Are you saying that you want to access/read multiple returned records? In any case, using the dot notation to reach the value of the key you want is not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get `Surname`, `Givenname`, and `Gender` from this JSON data:

```
     var Name = {
     "context" : {
     "priority" : "REALTIME",
     "properties" : [ ]
     },
     "inputPerson" : {
     "type" : "NaturalInputPerson",
     "personName" : {
     "nameFields" : [ {
     "string" : "Sample Name",
     "fieldType" : "FULLNAME"
      }]
    },
    "gender" : "UNKNOWN"
  }


  var options = {
 'method' : 'post',
 'contentType': 'application/json',
 'payload' : JSON.stringify(Name),
 
};


   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText();
   var data = JSON.parse(response);
   var gender =  data.bestMatch.parsedPerson.gender.gender;
   var Given =   data.bestMatch.parsedPerson.addressingGivenName; 
   var Surname = data.bestMatch.parsedPerson.addressingSurname;
```

Try it out and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I tried it, yeah it worked as I needed. Thank you for the solution, really appreciate it